# Как адаптировать toggle панель для всех браузеров?

Tags: jquery

Приветствую! Установлена раскрывающаяся панель с быстрым поиском на сайте.

```
$(".slide-panel-btn").click(function(){
    $("#slide-panel").slideToggle(250);
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});

<div class="slide-pannel-wrapper">
    <div id="slide-panel">
...                                          
    </div>
    <div class="slide-btn-wrapper">
       <a href="#" class="slide-panel-btn">
       </a>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Почему-то она работает как нужно только в firefox, потому-что к `<div id="slide-panel">` прописывается `style="overflow: hidden;"` и из-за этого содержимого быстрого поиска просто не видно.

Как сделать чтоб не добавлялся `style="overflow: hidden;"`

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно до конца ваша проблема, но чтобы убрать `style="overflow: hidden;"` можно написать так:

```
$(".slide-panel-btn").click(function(){
    $("#slide-panel").css("overflow","visible !important");
    $("#slide-panel").slideToggle(250);
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});
```